# How to deal with CKNotificationInfo 'desiredKeys' max 3 keys?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, cloudkit

I'm setting up my notification with 8 keys, that are the information that i need in the other device that will receive this notification. The problem is that the Documentation says that it's only possible to set 3 keys. Some of the information from this keys i can extract from the message, but I dont think thats it's the best way of doing that, such because this message can be in 8 different languages. How can i send this information with the push notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you prepare your notification, take a look at [CKNotificationInfo](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/cknotificationinfo). In this class you will find these properties:

- [alertLocalizationKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/cknotificationinfo/1514968-alertlocalizationkey)
- [alertActionLocalizationKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/cknotificationinfo/1514945-alertactionlocalizationkey)

You have to set properties above with an key of your localization strings file.

```
//In your .strings file...
"NOTICATION_BODY" = "¡Hola mundo!";
"NOTIFCATION_ACTION" = "Cerrar";

"NOTICATION_BODY" = "Hello world!";
"NOTIFCATION_ACTION" = "Close";

// In your CKNotificationInfo object...

notificationInfo.alertLocalizationKey = "NOTICATION_BODY"
notificationInfo.alertActionLocalizationKey= "NOTIFCATION_ACTION"
```

Comment: But how exactly this helps me sending all the 8 keys that I need? I'm not asking about localizing the strings of the notification, but how about i can send 8 keys at `desiredkeys` having only 3 keys limit available.

Comment: You mention something related to different languages. That's the reason of my response. You should obtain recordID from notification and execute a fetchRecordByID operation to recover the complete record. The operation is available in CKDatabase

Comment: It's safe to fetch a record before showing notification? I belive this occurs at `didReceive notification` method right?

Comment: You can fetch at any time, no matter if a notification occurs right now ;-). There's only one condition, the recordID must exists.

Comment: Perfect, just tried and worked perfectly. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using alertLocalizationArgs.  I was able to create 19 of them.